# How do I programmatically dial *#100# and retrieve my own phone number?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, phone-number

On a window mobile 6 phone I need to retrieve the phone number of the SIM card in the device.
I can manually dial *#100# and the phone number appears on the screen.

Does anybody know how to do this programmatically?

Preferably in C# but C++ will do, I can translate.

`SystemState.OwnerNumber` just returns an empty string (probably relies on the number being stored in the SIM correctly) but *#100# works.

Comment: `SystemState.OwnerNumber` gets its information from what the user configures in the owner details section of windows mobile.
Just spent a day bashing my head against RIL, no luck.
`RIL_GetSubscriberNumbers()` does nothing. No idea why, no error just 0 data returned.
Next had random stab at passing `*#100#` to RIL_Dial.
Connects, disconnects, not error and no useful data.

Answer (score 2):

The phone number isn't actually stored on the SIM card but in a mobile network database called HLR. There the user friendly phone number is matched with a subscription id called IMSI which is physically stored on your SIM card. 
So in order to retrieve the phone number your application must be allowed by the device to communicate on the network.

Comment: So, any idea how to query the HLR database?

Comment: other than the *#100# request you mentioned I don't know. I work for a company developing SIM card and mobile network applications/services, but I specify in GUI development for our products. What you're asking is way too back-end oriented for me to answer I'm afraid... =P

Comment: Will just have to hope somebody who knows how to use some mythical API comes along and knows how to programatically dial *#100# then. And damn Google for not letting me search for *#100# as well!
Thanks, J.

Comment: ohh yea, you're right.. well that's a bummer... makes things a bit harder... good luck man.

Answer (score 0):

A way to get the number on the sim card of a phone is to send an sms to some number which some server is listening on. The sms will carry along the phone number of the sender. Once your server receives the sms, the server can then send a push message to your client application with the phone number the client needs. Hope this helps.